# JPA Criteria - select enum from array

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an attribut status of type `enum` in my entity, in the query i want to pass an array of status to get all entities which their status exists in the array, so i used the predicate `in`, but i get this error

> Parameter value [INTEGRED] did not match expected type
>   [ConventionStatusEnum (n/a)]

```
@Entity
public class ConventionEntity implements Serializable {
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ConventionStatusEnum status;
}

CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ConventionEntity> query = cb.createQuery(ConventionEntity.class);
Root<ConventionEntity> convention = q.from(ConventionEntity.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> status= Arrays.asList(new String[]{"INTEGRED", "PUBLISHED"});
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(status )) {
  predicates.add(convention.get("status").in(status));
}

query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
TypedQuery<ConventionEntity> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
```

Comment: Your logic is right but have you tried  to change `List<String> status= Arrays.asList(new String[]{"INTEGRED", "PUBLISHED"});` to `List<String> status= Arrays.asList("INTEGRED", "PUBLISHED")` .
I think It is the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list `status` must be a list of `ConventionStatusEnum`:

```
List<ConventionStatusEnum> status = Arrays.asList(
    ConventionStatusEnum.INTEGRED,
    ConventionStatusEnum.PUBLISHED);
```

Basically the error message is telling that JPA implementation got a parameter of type `String` while it was expecting something of type `ConventionStatusEnum`.